# Could not find the '@nrwl/linter:eslint'

Tags: angular, nrwl, linter

i tried to install linter for my angular project but i get this error:
Could not find the '@nrwl/linter:eslint' builder's node package.

I installed all dependencies. I can't figure out what's wrong.

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "^16.1.4",
    "@nrwl/linter": "^16.1.4",
    ...
  }
```

Comment: `@nrwl/linter` deprecated, please check this page for more detail: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nrwl/linter. As per page you need to use `@nx/linter` instead of `@nrwl/linter`.

Comment: See this as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx